# Play video while downloading into local disk [AIR]

Tags: video, air

Using NetStream, I can create progressive video player. But can I save the downloaded chunk to my local disk in AIR??

My first idea is that, download part of file into local disk, let NetStream pointing to that file, and then appends the chunks to that file (FileMode.APPEND) periodically. But it does not work and seems that NetStream would 'lock' the file preventing write operation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was once a part of a project that tackled this exact problem. I'm pretty disappointed at how difficult Adobe makes writing flv to disk. I assume they do this to sell their media server (impossibly priced for what your doing), but who knows. We ended up using Neko media server, but its not perfect. Haxe or Red5 are also decent options